# Is a principal filter only generated by a single element?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, filters

Let $X$ be some non empty set . And
$$\mathscr{F}=\{A\subseteq X: i_0\in A\}$$
Now the mentioned $\mathscr{F}$ is a proper filter on $X$. Moreover it's a principal filter on $X$ generated by $i_0$.

Let us consider the following collection of subsets of $X$.
$$A=\{V\subseteq X:i_0,i_1\in V\}$$

My question:-
Is $A$ a proper filter on $X$ or not. If yes then is it a principal filter?

**My attempt:-**

Due to construction of $A$ , it was obvious to me that $A$ was a proper filter, but I was wondering if it is a principal filter or not. I read a couple of articles online which say that principle filter are generated by single elements. I read this [here](https://auislandora.wrlc.org/islandora/object/thesesdissertations%3A445)

Comment: Yes, it is a proper principal filter (generated by the subset 
$\{i_0,i_1\}$).The difference with the previous example is that this is not an ultrafilter and the previous example is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any subset $Y \subseteq X$, the set:
$$
\mathcal{F}_Y := \{A \subseteq X : Y \subseteq A\}
$$
is always a (proper) filter. By definition on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics)), a **principal filter** is a filter which is generated by some subset $Y \subseteq X$, i.e. it is of the form $\mathcal{F}_Y$ above. The set $A$ need not be a singleton - it doesn't even need to be finite.

However, one can prove that if an **ultrafilter** is also principal, then the set that generates it must be a singleton. In other words, if $Y \subseteq X$ and $\mathcal{F}_Y$ is an ultrafilter, then $Y = \{x_0\}$ for some $x_0 \in X$.

*Proof.* Suppose $Y$ has at least two distinct elements, say $x_0,x_1 \in Y$ and $x_0 \neq x_1$. Consider the set $A := X \setminus \{x_1\}$. Then $Y \not\subseteq A$ as $x_1 \notin A$, so $Y \notin \mathcal{F}_Y$. On the other hand, $X \setminus A = \{x_1\}$, and since $Y \not\subseteq X \setminus A$ we have that $X \setminus A \notin \mathcal{F}_Y$. Hence $\mathcal{F}_Y$ is not an ultrafilter. $\square$